# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I have an HTML5 form to submit comments on a blog.  For some reason, when you click submit, you see the following:

405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

I have no idea what this is pertaining to.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's your `<form method="???" ...` try `POST`

Comment: the form method is "post", but the action is "#"

Comment: The action needs to be the URL of the page or script that accepts and processes the form's data.

Comment: So if it is simply going to post a comment on a blog, I should just put the web page url in the action?

Comment: Now <form action="#"...   >  change to <form action="sampleblog.html"...  >?

Comment: Try it but that's what # would do (post to the same page) and the 405 error means the server is not allowing POSTs to HTML pages.  If you know for a fact the HTML page contains server side script to process a form and handle comments then its a server config problem; however usually comments would get posted to a different comment handling page.  This would depend on your specific platform and setup,  If you are in a hosted environment ask tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Check the method mentioned in your FORM tag

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
```

valid values are GET and POST. if empty default is GET

Comment: I have a '#' in the quotes for form action. I am not sure what I should have there.  Is it just the page url? Here is what I have:

Comment: <form action="#" method="post">  and let's say the page file name is blog.html.  What would I put there?

Comment: Thank you! I am working on the server side now. Once I get that straightened out, then I can re-test!